# Listar as postagens mais curtidas

Tags: php, facebook

Utilizando o [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) com a chamada abaixo:

```
 me?fields=posts{likes.summary(true).filter(stream)}
```

Recebo meus posts, quem curtiu e um sumário contendo o total:

```
{
    "posts": {
        "data": [{
            "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "likes": {
                "data": [{
                    "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                    "name": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
                }],
                "paging": {
                    "cursors": {
                        "before": "...",
                        "after": "..."
                    },
                    "next": "..."
                },
                "summary": {
                    "total_count": 35,
                    "can_like": true,
                    "has_liked": false
                }
            }
        }, {
            "id": "zzzzzzzzzzzzzz",
            "likes": {
                "data": [{
                    "id": "zzzzzzzzzzzzzz",
                    "name": "zzzzzzzzzzzzzz"
                }],
                "paging": {
                    "cursors": {
                        "before": "...",
                        "after": "..."
                    },
                    "next": "..."
                },
                "summary": {
                    "total_count": 30,
                    "can_like": true,
                    "has_liked": false
                }
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Dessa maneira ele me traz a quantidade de curtidas por postagem. Como listar os posts com mais curtidas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A API não disponibiliza isso, até onde eu saiba.

Você deverá tratar isso na sua aplicação, poderá usar:

```
$retorno = json_decode($curl, true);

uasort($retorno["posts"]["data"], function($a, $b) {
    return $b['likes']['summary']['total_count'] <=> $a['likes']['summary']['total_count'];
});
```

> O operador <=> está disponível apenas no PHP 7!

Isso irá ordenar a array ($retorno) do maior numero de curtidas até o menor, como deseja.

### Demonstração:

Para melhor demonstração, veja aqui:

**PHP:**

```
<?php

$json = json_decode('{
  "posts": {
    "data": [
      {
        "id": "a",
        "likes": {
          "summary": {
            "total_count": 4,
            "can_like": true,
            "has_liked": false
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "b",
        "likes": {
          "summary": {
            "total_count": 1,
            "can_like": true,
            "has_liked": false
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "c",
        "likes": {
          "summary": {
            "total_count": 3,
            "can_like": true,
            "has_liked": false
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "d",
                "likes": {
          "summary": {
            "total_count": 0,
            "can_like": true,
            "has_liked": false
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "e",
        "likes": {
          "summary": {
            "total_count": 1,
            "can_like": true,
            "has_liked": false
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "f",
        "likes": {
          "summary": {
            "total_count": 4,
            "can_like": true,
            "has_liked": false
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "g",
        "likes": {
          "summary": {
            "total_count": 5,
            "can_like": true,
            "has_liked": false
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "paging": {
      "previous": "",
      "next": ""
    }
  },
  "id": ""
}', true);



uasort($json["posts"]["data"], function($a, $b) {
    return $b['likes']['summary']['total_count'] <=> $a['likes']['summary']['total_count'];
});


foreach($json["posts"]["data"] as $postagens){

    echo 'Postagem: '.$postagens['id'].' contem '.$postagens['likes']['summary']['total_count'].' curtidas';
    echo '<br>';

}
```

**Resposta:**

```
Postagem: g contem 5 curtidas
Postagem: a contem 4 curtidas
Postagem: f contem 4 curtidas
Postagem: c contem 3 curtidas
Postagem: b contem 1 curtidas
Postagem: e contem 1 curtidas
Postagem: d contem 0 curtidas
```

[Se preferir veja isto no PHP Sandbox.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/419324073b916fd507bcc7a1fe86c50a891ccd09)

> Eu editei alguns retornos da API, para esconder alguns dados (como quem curtiu, id das minhas publicações...), porém preservei todas os índices.